# How can I create an overlay with slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create something like that with **slick slider**:

[image: layout]

This overlay with slider should appear after clicking on button. I think that i should use the slick slider's center mode. I know how to style colors, widths and so on, but i can't to implement the above-described structure.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple way to achieve this, following is a example I created using lightbox, you can get the idea from here, check the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/99guewhk/)

**CSS**

```
#pageOverLay {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    margin-left: 43%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    z-index: 1001;
    visibility:hidden;
}
#pageOverLay-shadow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    -moz-opacity: 0.75;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.75;
    opacity: 0.75;
    z-index: 1000;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#pageOverLayCloseBtn {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
.slick-slider {
    margin: 30px auto 50px;
}
.slick-slider {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
 $("#openLB").on("mousedown","",showLightBox);

function showLightBox() {
     $("#pageOverLay-shadow").css("visibility", "visible");
     $("#pageOverLay").css("visibility", "visible");

 }

 $("#pageOverLayCloseBtn").on("mousedown","",pageOverLayClose);

 function pageOverLayClose() {
     $("#pageOverLay-shadow").css("visibility", "hidden");
     $("#pageOverLay").css("visibility", "hidden");
 }
 var disqus_shortname = 'slickcarousel';

 (function () {
     var dsq = document.createElement('script');
     dsq.type = 'text/javascript';
     dsq.async = true;
     dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
     (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
 })();
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="openLB" href="#">Click Here to show lightbox</a>
<div id="pageOverLay-shadow"></div>
<div id="pageOverLay">
  <div id="pageOverLayCloseBtn"><a href="#" onclick="pageOverLayClose();">X</a> </div>
  <h2>Images</h2>
  <div class="slider fade">
    <div>
      <div class="image"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-94/data1/images/photo1427806208781b36531cb09ef.jpg" /> </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="image"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-94/data1/images/photo142855067022515f007f6f1ba.jpg" /> </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="image"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-94/data1/images/photo1428452788387375d846a8ab4.jpg" /> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```